Replace deprecated Angular ComponentFactoryResolver
How can I rewrite the code so it's nt using deprecated ComponentFactoryResolver and still does the same stuff (open a modal in the body)?
import { ComponentFactoryResolver, Inject, Injectable, Injector, TemplateRef } from "@angular/core";
import { ModalComponent } from "../../shared/components/modal/modal.component";
import { DOCUMENT } from "@angular/common";
import { Observable, Subject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class ModalService {
  private modalNotifier?: Subject<string>;
  constructor(
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private injector: Injector,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document
  ) {}

  open(content: TemplateRef<any>, options?: { size?: string; title?: string }): Observable<string> {
    const modalComponentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(
      ModalComponent
    );
    const contentViewRef = content.createEmbeddedView(null);
    const modalComponent = modalComponentFactory.create(this.injector, [
      contentViewRef.rootNodes,
    ]);

    modalComponent.instance.size = options?.size;
    modalComponent.instance.title = options?.title;
    modalComponent.instance.closeEvent.subscribe(() => this.closeModal());
    modalComponent.instance.submitEvent.subscribe(() => this.submitModal());

    modalComponent.hostView.detectChanges();

    this.document.body.appendChild(modalComponent.location.nativeElement);
    this.modalNotifier = new Subject();
    return this.modalNotifier?.asObservable();
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.modalNotifier?.complete();
  }

  submitModal() {
    this.modalNotifier?.next('confirm');
    this.closeModal();
  }
}


I tryed using instead of the factory
const contentViewRef = content.createEmbeddedView(null);
const component = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(ModalComponent, {
  injector: this.injector,
  projectableNodes: [
    contentViewRef.rootNodes
  ],
})

But I get a blank html sheet after those changes
