Two way data binding does not work inside ng-template
My selectedContent and selectedSummary can not be displayed (blank).
The string inside <p> instead is displayed.
<ng-template #modalTemplate>
  <div class="scroll-container">
    <div class="left-content">
      <div class="scrollable-text" >
        {{ selectedContent }}
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-content">
      <div class="scrollable-text">
        {{ selectedSummary }}
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>

In .ts I have a method that opens the modal when cklicking on inspect. In this Method I set the content and the summary, pass it to my modalService which appends that modal to the body and displays it.
  onInsepctTranscription(modalTemplate: TemplateRef<any>, content: string, summary: string) {
    console.log('On inspect');
    this.selectedContent = content;
    this.selectedSummary = summary;
    console.log('Content', this.selectedContent);

    this.modalService
      .open(modalTemplate, { size: 'lg', title: 'Foo' })
      .subscribe((action) => {
        console.log('modalAction', action);
      });
  }

Also those two properties are declared as fallowed:
selectedContent = 'NO CONTENT'; selectedSummary = 'NO SUMMARY';
When I move everything outside the ng-template the selectedContent and selectedSummary are displayed but inside the ng-template I can only display hard coded strings.
I tried a lot of things at this point. I checked my scss whether it's because of that. I checked for errors in the consol. I checked whether the properties are set with the correct value (which if it where not, it should display at least the default values)
THE WHOLE HTML
<app-page-layout>
  <div class="content-layout">
    <h1 id="page-title" class="content__title">Transcriptions</h1>
    <div class="content__body">
      <ul class="accordion">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of transcriptions; let first = first">
          <li class="accordion-list">
            <div class="accordion-item" (click)="selectItem(item.id)">
              <app-transcription [transcriptionItem]="item" [isChecked]="first"></app-transcription>
              <i class='bx bx-chevron-right chevron-right-icon' *ngIf="item.id === selectedItemId"></i>
              <!-------MENU------->
              <div class="transcription-menu">
                <div class="menu-item" (click)="onDeleteTranscription(item.id)">
                  <i class='bx bx-trash'></i>
                  <span>Delete</span>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-item" (click)="onInsepctTranscription(modalTemplate, item.content, item.summary)">
                  <i class='bx bx-book-open'></i>
                  <span>Inspect</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!------------------>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ng-container>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</app-page-layout>

<ng-template #modalTemplate>
  <div class="scroll-container">
    <div class="left-content">
      <div class="scrollable-text" >
        {{ selectedContent }}
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-content">
      <div class="scrollable-text">
        {{ selectedSummary }}
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>


Can you please provide the html where you are triggering the modal to open.

what is modalService? it seems it attaches the template somwhere where change detection isn't triggering  for it. if  you are using pretty new Angular you can make those values signals

My Modal Service: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78392244/replace-deprecated-angular-componentfactoryresolver

If the modal is opening properly and the content inside the <p> tag is displayed then here are some debugging steps that could help:

Make sure that selectedContent and selectedSummary are accessible to your  block.
You can try manual change detection using ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() inside the onInsepctTranscription
Or you can try using the BehaviorSubject from rxjs for those variables.


I already tryed ChangeDerectorRef.detectChanges and the properties are accessible just not inside ng-template
